# How to protect "register" API route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a back end in Laravel for an Android/iPhone APP. I am currently usine JWT-AUTH package for authentication but I have noticed that `/register` route is pretty much open and if someone wanted, they could create a rogue app and spam my back end with fake registrations.

Is there a way to prevent it? I do not want to use Passport because I would then have to hardcode client_id and client_secret in the mobile app anyway.

Comment: Which part are you protecting your app from? You can throttle the requests (max X every Y minutes). You can log IP and prevent creating more than 1 register from same IP every X hours. As long as you want the register to be available for anyone, it will be an arms race of what you'll protect against and what the attacker could use. Unless there's a real added value for the users to have multiple accounts, throttling is usually enough.

Comment: @devk Thanks, throttling is already in place but I was wondering if there is something else that devs do and I don't ;) I was thinking along the lines of somehow identifying the mobile app and only allowing that speciffic app to ever use the API. It would mean having some sort of secret key hardcoded into mobile app, which is hackable for anyone who can decompile the app.

Comment: @Varin Hi ! I was wondering if you found a solultion, everyone is suggesting me to use a middleware, but I can't, because there isn't a user logged in when someone register, Therefore I don't have any information to validate with a middleware.

Answer (score -2):

The best way would be to alter the constructor of ***app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php*** to use the **auth** middleware instead of **guest**.

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This will make it so a user has to be logged in in order to view the register route.

An alternative method would be to manually copy 
the routes (without the registration routes) from the **auth()** method in ***Illuminate\Routing\Router.php*** and replace **Auth::routes()** in your web routes file with the following

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Doing this will completely remove the registration routes.

Comment: I know I can use auth middleware to protect the routes... the whole point though is that register route should not be using middleware as I can't expect an user to be logged in in order to register....

Comment: @Varin im having the same issue your facing, and im didnt find any valid answer, did you found a solution? Im using Laravel passport

Comment: @Varin did you come up or learn of a solution?